# requesting internet permission not working

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to request internet permission in my android app on my android phone using SDK 26. I've tried using the `AndroidManifest.xml`, I've tried using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.INTERNET }, 1);` and I've tried different request codes. I've tried this in `onCreate` and inside a button press event, but still no permissions show up when I go into the App Info.

I'm totally lost as I don't see any reason why this won't work. any Ideas? common problems that I don't know of yet?

### andoidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simplevents">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share your complete code and the logcat message.

Comment: You don't need to ask for internet permission at runtime, declaring it in the manifest is enough. Could you please post your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: internet permission is a normal persmission not dangerous , you dont need to request it programmatically , just add it in manifest

Comment: @NovoLucas there is no error, so what exactly do you want from the logcat?

Comment: @lelloman I added it to the post, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @Quicklearner I don't care about the dialog, I just want it to work. No permissions show up on the App Info screen, so it doesn't work or am I wrong?

Comment: just add this 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in Manifest , that is enough

Comment: @Quicklearner did you even look at my post

Comment: Internet permission is normal permission and it never shows in app info. Just declaring in manifest file is enough. And the permission popup also not display bcoz system allow the permission by-default.

Comment: The maifest looks ok, so what is exactly your issue?

Comment: @lelloman I guess something else was the issue, but Android just told me it couldn't execute the button handler, nothing more. I assumed it was the internet permission because it wouldn't show up on the app info -> permissions screen. and now I can't delete the question because other people have already put so much effort into answering it (no seriously that's why stackoverflow won't let me delete it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I'm not allowed to delete this question any more because other people have already put effort into answering the question, I will explain to you what my error was. I did have the permission for internet access the whole time - so I had a completely different fault in my code, and I misinterpreted the error message and thought it was a permission thing, because the internet permission doesn't show up on the app info screen. It never does, because it's not a 'dangerous' permission, that much I've learned.

To summarize: Getting the permission to establish a connection to the internet on android is as easy as adding the permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 6):

Permissions are divided into several protection levels

There are three protection levels that affect third-party apps: **normal**, **signature**, and **dangerous** permissions

`INTERNET` permission comes in *normal protection* level and that's why it's not required to ask at runtime

see list [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#normal-dangerous)

What is *normal* and *dangerous* permission?

**Normal** :

The permissions which are not sensitive and harmful to users eg. like **VIBRATE** and **INTERNET**

**Dangerous** :

The permissions which are sensitive and harmful like after allowing **READ_CONTACTS**, The App can misuse your contacts details or allow **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** can access your SD card data

Answer (score 5):

You don't need special Permission for Internet.

Just Define Permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

for testing purpose you can check your internet connection add below permission in Android Manifest file. This Permission give you what is state (Status) of your internet connection.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Here Test Code you can using check you internet connection. isNetwork function return true if internet service is working otherwise it returns false.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        if (isNetwork(getApplicationContext())){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Is Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }


    public boolean isNetwork(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Internet** Permission in Normal permission, This permission allow automatically by Android System.

Only Sensitive Permission like CALL_LOG, SMS etc.. are need Run time Permission.

Try this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

If you are using mobile data , you need only INTERNET permission
but if you using Wi-Fi or other network, you need ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission,

Note- Network permission do not need on Runtime permission.